# Multiple images in ICO

Tags: c#, winforms, ico

I created an ICO file with 2 images in it, one 32*32 and one 16*16 in order to let the application pick one for the process window and one for the taskbar. However all it does is simple use the image (with 2 images in it) for both. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: How did you create the ico? There are many free tools out there you can try.

Comment: I created a PNG in photoshop then used an online PNG to ICO convertor. I just placed the images along side each other. Do I need to do anything special?

Comment: Try to open it in VisualStudio, you should see if there're 2 images or one. Or you may draw an icon in VS with different sizes - sure way.

Comment: Looks like one icon to me. How can I tell visual studio to see it as 2 icons?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it. Here is the full guide:

http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/favicon.html

Comment: Why do you make it sound like posting my own answer is a bad thing? I just put it there just in case someone was having the same problem.

Comment: Posting your own answer is never bad, in fact very good as you pointed out. I only meant that you should work on accepting answers and the least you can accept your own answers. But yeah as I look now 72 is not that bad. For a moment I read it different, apologies..:)

Comment: Like I said you have to wait 2 days and I end up forgetting after 2 days :P

Comment: It's been more than two days @TheGateKeeper I think you can accept now